# Find all surjective functions $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ such that $f\big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=f(x+y)$, $f(2)=0$ and $f(x)\ne0$ for $0\le x<2$

Tags: solution-verification, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f$ mapping the non-negative reals onto the non-negative reals such that:
>
> - $f\big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=f(x+y)$ for all non-negative $x,y$,
> - $f(2)=0$,
> - and $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $0\le x <2$.

I do not think any such functions exist. My reasoning is as follows:

**Proof:** Assume there is a function $f$ satisfying the above. A few simple calculations show that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$.

Assume $x>2$, then there exists $y$ such that $y+2=x$. It follows then that
$$f\big(yf(2)\big)f(2)=f(x) \implies 0=f(x)\text.$$

Thus $f(x)=0$, for all $x\ge2$.

Next, consider some $y\in (0,1)$. There exists $x\in(1,2)$, such that $x+y=2$, and so
$$f\big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=0 \implies f\big(xf(y)\big)=0 \implies f(y)>1\text.$$

Thus, for all $y\in (0,1)$, we have $f(y)\in (1,2)$.

Since $f$ is onto, for any $a\in(0,1)$, there must exist a non-negative $x$ such that $f(x)=a$. Further, by above we must have $x\in (1,2)$. Arguing as before, there exists $y\in(0,1)$ such that $x+y=2$. Hence
$$f\big(yf(x)\big)f(x)=0 \implies f(ya)=0\text.$$

However, by our choice of $y$ we have $ 0<ya<1$, and so $f(ya)$ cannot equal zero. Thus, there are no functions $f$ which satisfy these criteria. $\quad \square$

Comment: Your reasoning seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an answer that people can vote on if they concur,

#### Yes your proof is correct.